# How do split panes, scroll panes & layouts work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I'm trying to make this sort of UI in Java swing where you can drag and drop things from the left menu into one of the cells in the middle like this image where the left and right side is collapsible:

[What I'm trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSNud.png)

My current attempts have left me at this weird stage:
[What actually happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A56EV.png)

What's even stranger is that what I've already put into the left panel only appears after I hover my mouse over it and it'll disappear again after I resize it using the split. Also only one of the panels I added to the panel appears and I can't get the second one to appear:
[After moving divider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBKjK.png)
[Mouse moved over button now appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rE3e.png)

And in my graph area, the buttons refuse to move to the top of the graph unless I move the divider so that the panel is small enough to force it to the top. Relevant code is here:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.jfree.data.time.DynamicTimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.time.Second;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

/**
 * @author CephDigital
 *
 */
public class GUI extends JFrame{
    
    DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset;
    private Timer timer;
    ActionListener timerAction = new ActionListener() {
        float newData[] = new float[1];
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Store new data to newData
            dataset.advanceTime();
            dataset.appendData(newData);
        }
    };
    
    int size = 20;
    DefaultComponent[][] graph = new DefaultComponent[size][size];
    
    String saveDirectory = "";
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int screenWidth = (int)screenSize.getWidth(),
        screenHeight = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
    
    JButton btnGraphStart = new JButton("Place first point"),
            btnGraphEnd = new JButton("Place end point"),
            hidePower = new JButton("Power"),
            hideResist = new JButton("Resistors"),
            startSimulation = new JButton("Start"),
            endSimulation = new JButton("End");
    
    JMenuBar optionsBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem menuItem;
    
    JPanel  topMenuPanel = new JPanel(),
            //compPanel = new JPanel(),
            gridPanel = new JPanel(),
            graphPanel = new JPanel(),
            itemPanel,
            globalPanel = new JPanel(),
            resistorComps = new JPanel(),
            resistorTotal = new JPanel(),
            powerComps = new JPanel(),
            powerTotal = new JPanel();
    
    JScrollPane compPanel = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    
    JToolBar simulationControl = new JToolBar("Simulation Control");
    
    JSlider light;
    JLabel lightTxt;
    
    public GUI() {
        //Setting up split panels
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        compPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        gridPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(size,size));
        graphPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        
        
        JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, compPanel, gridPanel);
        sp.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        sp.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
        //sp.setDividerLocation(500);
        JSplitPane sp2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, sp, graphPanel);
        sp2.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        //sp2.setDividerLocation(700);
        
        //Setup the menu for the components panel
        hideResist.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (resistorComps.isVisible()) {
                    resistorComps.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    resistorComps.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
        hidePower.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (powerComps.isVisible()) {
                    powerComps.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    powerComps.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
        
        //Panel for different power IO
        powerComps.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        powerTotal.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        powerTotal.add(hidePower);
        powerTotal.add(powerComps);
        powerTotal.setSize(200, 200);
        compPanel.add(powerTotal);
        
        //Panel for different types of resistors
        resistorComps.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
        resistorTotal.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        resistorTotal.add(hideResist);
        resistorTotal.add(resistorComps);
        powerTotal.setSize(200, 200);
        compPanel.add(resistorTotal);
        
        //compPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        //compScroll.add(compPanel);
        
        //Setup the grid panel
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
                //Create a panel
                itemPanel = new JPanel();
                itemPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
                itemPanel.setSize(100, 100);
                itemPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
                gridPanel.add(itemPanel);
            }
        }
        
        //Setup the graph panel
        float[] voltageData = {};
        dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 2 * 60, new Second());
        dataset.setTimeBase(new Second(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2011));
        dataset.addSeries(voltageData, 0, "Voltage");
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(btnGraphStart);
        buttonPanel.add(btnGraphEnd);
        
        graphPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        graphPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        graphPanel.add(new ChartPanel(chart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 240);
            }
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        //Setup the global panel for global variables that the user can change
        light = new JSlider(1, 100000, 1);
        light.addChangeListener((ChangeEvent e) -> {
            float text = (float)(light.getValue()) / 10;
            lightTxt.setText(Float.toString(text));
        });
        lightTxt = new JLabel("0.1");
        createLayout(globalPanel, new JLabel("Global Lux"), light, lightTxt);
        
        //Set the location of components in the frame
        this.setTitle("Circuit Simulator");
        this.add(topMenuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(sp2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(globalPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(1243, 679);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }
    
    private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
                "Title", "mm:ss", "Voltage", dataset, true, true, false);
        XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
        ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setAutoRange(true);
        ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(0, 10);
        return result;
    }
    
    private void createLayout(JComponent...arg) {
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) arg[0];
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(gl);
        
        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        
        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[1])
                .addComponent(arg[2])
                .addComponent(arg[3])
        );
        
        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[1])
                .addComponent(arg[2])
                .addComponent(arg[3])
        );
        
        pack();
    }
}
```

I hate GUI making so someone please help me figure this nonsense out.

Comment: Edit your question and include the code which creates all those panels and sets their layouts.  We need a [mre] so we can see your problem for ourselves.  That said, you may want to read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/ to gain a clear understanding of layouts.

Comment: Alright the code was properly edited. Should be able to recreate the issue now.

Comment: That is NOT an [mre]. Your question is about the layout of components. Using a component from JFreeChart is irrelevant to this question. Your are using 3rd party classes that I don't have access to. You can just use a JLabel or something to represent the chart. In any case your last question is about why the component on the left doesn't display. You seemed to miss the comment about problem solving one step at a time. Where is your MRE, that simply displays the left panel in your split pane? Also all the ActionListeners are irrelevant to the stated question. A listener doesn't affect layout.

Comment: @CephDigital The menu bar is is irrelevant to the stated problem. With a proper MRE the entire code would be maybe 30 lines of code. A couple lines to create the frame. A couple to create the split panel. A few more to create your nested panels for the left component. Here is an example of an MRE that deals with a problem using a split pane. You should be able do modify it to create your "left panel" in an attempt to get it to display the way you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45929359/131872. Once you get a basic example working you fix your real application.

Answer (score 2):

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout. Your code is incomplete but it looks to me like both your compPanel and graphPanel are using the default layout manager so the layout is not what you expect.

You need to set the appropriate layout manager and nest panels when necessary to achieve your desired effect.

For example for the graphPanel I would suggest you can do something like:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(...) ); // center aligned
buttonPanel.add(btnGraphStart);
buttonPanel.add(btnGraphEnd);

ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPane(chart);

graphPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
graphPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
graphPanel.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

So now the buttons will be displayed at the top in a row and the chart will be displayed below the buttons.

Use the appropriate layout for the compPanel as well. Maybe use a vertical BoxLayout, then you can add the two child panels.

Comment: Well that fixed the button issue, thanks! Any recommendations on the left panel? I find it weird that it only makes the panels appear after I hover my mouse over them when there's nothing in the code that makes it do that.

Comment: I made a suggestion. You still haven't posted your [mre]. So start by creating a JFrame with just that panel added to the split pane. I can never figure out why people write the entire code before testing. So my advice is start simple and test. Then add more code and test. That is create one panel and test it displays as expected. Then create another and retest etc. It is much easier to debug smaller chunks of code.

Comment: I changed the code so it's reproducable now.